# connect two vlans in cisco switch to one server

Tags: routing, vlan, switching

I have two VLANs on a Cisco switch. The first VLAN includes 24 PCs and the second has another 24 PCs. Now the company has decided to install a server for these computers.

How can we connect these VLANs to one server without changing the network ID of the computers or installing a new router?

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1:**

You will have to make the new server the router or gateway for all the PCs connected to the switch. 
You will also have to make the server present on all VLANs (by creating virtual IP interfaces on it) and also connecting it to a trunk VLAN port on the switch, so it can route traffic from one VLAN to another.

**Scenario 2:**

You could also connect the server to both VLANs using two physical network interfaces on it, each of which is connected to every VLAN that has PCs (that need to access the server) on it.
This will use up two ports instead of one as the example above would.

**Note:**

This is assuming that your server can be configured this way.

Otherwise you will most likely have to involve a router.

Comment: Scenario 2 would be the most straight-forward solution, without involving routers or advanced configuration.